# NSArray into NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdata

I am building an iOS app.i am facing a problem to convert nsarray to nsstring.

I am getting in nsarray *ys_avatars is

```
           - data : {
               message = "User Created!";
             userid = 547awdg7863hda7980855;}
```

I want to store this userid in string.

here is my code:

```
   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
   ys_avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];

   NSArray  *results=[ys_avatars valueForKey:@"userid"];//i'm getting userid here in results array
   NSString *str = [results objectAtIndex:0];// i'm getting nil in the string
```

Comment: userid looks like a string to me already. Why are you putting it into an array?

Answer (score 1):

Since userid has no quotes, it probably is not going to be considered valid JSON. If it was a number, this might be valid JSON, but it contains characters that are not valid in base-10 or base-16 numbers. Either way, I don't think this value will be interpreted as an array.

You might want to check if there is a valid pointer in "results" before trying to use it. It is probably nil. "ys_avatars" may be nil too.